# Is there any way to access a property like SKSpriteNode in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, uikit

I have some experience in `SKSpriteKit` and I am writing code in UIViewController using UIKit library. And I wonder if I could access existing propteries such as ones from `UILabel`, `UITextField`, `UIView`, and so on. In Swift, nodes can be named and called by their names using `childWithName(name: String)`, so is there any way to do this in UIKit. ? I thought doing this would be much more convenienet and my writing would go smooth. I started programming in UIKit so I do not know much about it, so I appreciate if you teach me abou this!

Thankyou

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't give "names" to `UIView`s as far as I'm concerned. However, there's something similar.

You can set a view's `tag` by doing:

```
someView.tag = 1
```

Then, assuming that `superView` is the super view of `someView`, you can do this to get `someView`:

```
superView.viewWithTag(1)
```

It's not as descriptive as `name`, but you can use named constants to make it clearer:

```
let scoreLabelTag = 1
superView.viewWithTag(scoreLabelTag)
```

Comment: ah I see. Tag! Now I see ! Thanks :))